# Check if a given series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I wanted to check if the sum $\sum_{n>0}\frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges.

As $n!$ grows faster than $n^n$, I first thought that it would be divergent. But this doesn't seem to be true, as I found out later using wolfram alpha. So the first thing I don't understand, is why it converges, as normally a factorial function grows faster than a polynomial one?

I then tried to use the root test criteria to check the series:

$lim_{n->\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\sqrt[n]{|\frac{n!}{n^n}|}= |\frac{\sqrt[n]n!}{n}| = |\frac{(n(n-1)!)^\frac{1}{n}}{n}|= |\frac{n^{-n}(n-1)!^\frac{1}{n}}{n}| = |\frac{(n-1)!^{-n}}{n^{n+1}}| $

So I think that the numerator goes to $- \infty$ and the denominator goes to $+\infty$, which leads to an undefined form. Therefore I want to differentiate the numerator and denumerator to apply the rule of de l'Hospital, but again I get an undefined form.

Therefore I tried to solve it using another criteria and started from the beginning:

$lim_{n->\infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=|\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=|\frac{n^n{(n+1)!}}{n!(n+1)^{n+1}}|= |\frac{n^n{(n+1)}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}| = |n^n{(n+1)(n+1)^{-n-1}}| = |n^n(n+1)^{-n}|= |\frac{n^n}{n^n+1}|= |\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n^n}}|=1 $

As the value is exactly $1$, I can't say if it converges or not. So what am I doing wrong again. Can it in general be solved with one of these two criteria, and what would be the easiest way to solve it?

Comment: if you look up Stirling's approximation, your term is about $\frac{\sqrt n}{e^n}$ and the sum converges    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: $n^n$ is not a polynomial function though. $n^n$ is the product of $n$ numbers which are all $n$. $n!$ is the product of $n$ numbers that only one of them is $n$, the others are smaller. So $n!$ can't grow faster than $n^n$.

Comment: $$O(n^n)>O(n!)>O(k^n)>O(n^k)>O(n)>O(\log n)>O(1)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. You've just misused the ratio test criterion:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} = \frac{1}{e} < 1
\end{align*}

**EDIT**

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\frac{n}{n+1} &= \frac{(n+1)-1}{n+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \Longrightarrow\\
\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n} & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n} = \left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{-1}\Longrightarrow\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n} & = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\times\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}
Given that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{-1} = 1\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} = e
\end{align*}
Can you deduce from here the remaining steps?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to get to the second step (the one before the e-function). If I pull one $n$ out, I get $(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}})^n$

Comment: I edited my answer in order to explain the intermediate steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only thing I don't understand is, how to come from $(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}$ to $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$.
I came until $(1+\frac{n}{n+1})^{n+1}$ but I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Make the substitution $u = -(n+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You made an error in the calculation for the ratio test...  (there's an extra factor of $(n+1))$:  the limit is in fact $\frac1e\lt1$.  So it converges.

(Recall:  $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n=e$).

Comment: Thanks, but in which step have you found the error, as I still can't see it?

Comment: After the $4$th equal sign:  $\mid\frac{n^n(n+1)}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\mid=\mid\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\mid$.

Comment: Actually,  technically your mistake comes the $3$rd equality from the end.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove the convergence of the given series you only need very crude bounds, like the one provided by the AM-GM inequality, for instance. For any $n>1$ we have
$$ \frac{n!}{n^n}=\text{GM}\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\ldots,\frac{n}{n}\right)^n<\text{AM}\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\ldots,\frac{n}{n}\right)^n=\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}\right)^n\leq\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n $$
hence convergence is granted by a comparison with a geometric series.

Comment: Looks really interesting. I've never heared about the "AM-GM inequality" before.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge 2,$

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\cdots \frac{2}{n}\frac{1}{n}\le \frac{2}{n^2}.$$

Since $\sum \dfrac{2}{n^2} <\infty,$ $\sum \dfrac{n!}{n^n}<\infty$ by the comparison test.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I still don't have enough experience to be able to see immediately, that the series is $<= \frac{2}{n^2}$

Comment: The last two fractions give you the $2/n^2.$ All the rest of the fractions are $\le 1.$